# Ignore the Temp folder created by Unity

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

`mainFolder` >> contains '.git' and 'projectFolder'

`projectFolder` >> contains '.gitignore' and 'Temp' folder alongwith other folders

Following are the contents of my gitignore file

```
*.bin
*.suo
*.user
projectFolder/obj
projectFolder/Temp
projectFolder/Library
```

Even though the /Temp folder is present in the gitignore, when I check the git status it shows up the Temp folder in the red untracked files list. I have tried using projectFolder/Temp/ as well, and moving the gitignore file to mainFolder. But nothing worked. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you already `git add`ed the `projectFolder/Temp` folder or anything in it?

Comment: No, i did not add it. It's new folder which gets created whenever the Project runs in Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this line to gitignore:

```
/[Tt]emp/
```

I always prefer to this Git Ignore file:

[UnityGitIgnore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)

Comment: I used it with unity 5.5, github and windows. i never tried unity on mac. gitignore.io has also exact same ingore file. These ignore files are updated soon and used by many people without having problem.

Comment: Great. i added myself to those list of users :)

Answer (score 2):

If your `.gitignore` file is already inside a sub folder, you should list paths and patterns relative to that folder.

In your case, since it is already inside `projectFolder`, it should contain :

```
obj/
Temp/
Library/
```

to ignore the folders you mentionned.

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out. Earlier I thought it is something peculiar to Unity. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

While [@LEGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) will solve it for you, the recommended practise is to have the `.gitignore` file at the root of your project.

In that case, you only need to issue one command and this would take care of itself:

```
git mv projectFolder/.gitignore .. && git commit -m "Moving gitignore to parent directory"
```

Alternatively, if your actual project is `projectFolder`, you need to initialize the git repo within that project directory and not in the project's parent folder.

Edit: If you are worried about losing all the history of commits, you can 1) do a `git mv projectFolder/* ..` and commit those changes. 2) Then, rename the `mainFolder` as `project Folder`, and 3) nest it under another new folder, and name this new folder as `mainFolder`. In case you want to be extra cautious, just make a copy of the `mainFolder` and try these in the copied folder. Its easier to correct this now than later in your dev cycle :)

Comment: yes, you are correct. I should have initialized git inside the projectFolder. But I can't undo it now, or rather I don't want to :(

Comment: @vipin8169 If you are worried about losing all the history of commits, you can 1) do a `git mv projectFolder/* ..` and commit those changes. 2) Then, rename the `mainFolder` as `project Folder`, and 3) nest it under another new folder, and name this new folder as `mainFolder`.

Comment: @vipin8169 If you want to be extra cautious, just make a copy of the `mainFolder` and try these in the copied folder. Its easier to correct this now than later in your dev cycle :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try :)